# Why do I get different results with gdal_calc within the osgeo4w shell and QGIS' raster calculator?

Tags: gdal, osgeo

I'm just wanting to make a simple map algebra operation in the osgeo4w shell using gdal_calc but I get wrong results when I divide one raster with the other. When I use the same rasters in QGIS and perform the same map algebra operation with raster calculator, I get no problem.

Comment: Hi vascobrunes, could you clarify how the output is incorrect. Also, have you checked if you are using the cmdline syntax correctly for gdal_calc?

Comment: For example: I'm doing a simple calculation and getting this: Error! Dimensions of file  are different from other files.  Cannot proceed
while if I do it in QGIS it works fine

Answer (score 3):

I think my best guess would be that you should clip one raster using the other, and save the results as a .vrt to save time.

use this vrt in your previous gdal_calc calculation. that should work.

side-note: The answer is actually in the Error message. I dug a bit deeper and looked at the code here ( http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py ). A comment at the tops specifies that rasters should be of the same extent.

LATER EDIT: If your problem appears to be that the values are too big for your data type this is because gdalcalc determines the data type based on the input rasters not the appropriate output data size (i believe from the link I provide you can search data type and you'll see the comment).

I am not sure of the options to change data type in the gdalcalc syntax but you could precede your calculation by translating your input raster with gdaltranslate into a larger data type;32bit-float should be fine. saving as a vrt will also save time `gdal_translate -ot Float32 -of VRT old.tif new.vrt`

link: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Still Later Edit: I actually checked gdal_calc.py on my comp and found it has a `--type` parameter you can enter from the command line. I think this will work for your problem

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I solved it by first using gdalwarp on the raster files.

Comment: Hey, if you write up your solution other people might benefit. As well, I won't think it is 'unsolved' ;) btw, glad you figured it out.

Comment: It is still unsolved: I still get different results from using gdal_calc or the qgis raster calculator. With gdal_calc, in a raster with 0 and 1, if I do raster*88 its good. but if I do raster*2012257 the result is weird. I QGIS raster calculator the result is what was expected (2012257).

Comment: seems like the value I use in gdal_calc can't be bigger than 30999

Comment: Hey vasco, I hope my latest edits fix your problem. If not, perhaps we could look at the code you are using.

Comment: A part of the solution is here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4064

for this: "Gdal_calc performs calculations using the native data type of the original input layers, which can be problematic if, say, you are dividing two integers and expect a float output."

Comment: good discussion, so, qgis rules =)