# Inconsistency with calculations of QGIS raster calculator and gdal_calc.py

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm trying to compute a DEM using simple matrix algebra (DSM - DTM) but am running into a problem. The resulting `.tif` from the QGIS raster calculator is different to the output of `gdal_calc.py`.

The command I am using is:

```
gdal_calc.py -A nt6905_DSM_1M.tif -B nt6905_DTM_1M.tif --outfile=test.tif --calc="A-B" --format=GTiff --type=Float32 --debug
```

Following the answer in [Why do I get different results with gdal_calc within the osgeo4w shell and QGIS' raster calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33152/why-do-i-get-different-results-with-gdal-calc-within-the-osgeo4w-shell-and-qgis), I've changed the datatype parameter accordingly but am still returning different results.

Does anybody know how I can fix this? Is QGIS even using `gdal_calc.py` under the hood?

Sam

Comment: In which way the results are different? Can you share test data?

Comment: @user30184 I've shared some tif files here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qtmocaswuq7i4d5/AAAv6QksIXk90dPsZnNCEybHa?dl=0

I can tell by the min and max that the resulting files are different.

Comment: There seems to be several raster calculators available in QGIS https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3779.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anybody is interested, I managed to replicate the raster calculation using the QGIS Python console. Script is below and provides the expected output.

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings

crs = 'EPSG:27700' 
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehaviour', 'useGlobal')
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/layerDefaultCrs', crs)

dsm = ["C:/xampp/htdocs/dt6905_DSM_1M.tif", "C:/xampp/htdocs/dt6906_DSM_1M.tif"] 
dtm = ["C:/xampp/htdocs/dt6905_DTM_1M.tif", "C:/xampp/htdocs/dt6906_DTM_1M.tif"]

for i, (s,t) in enumerate(zip(dsm,dtm)):

    dsmLayer  = QgsRasterLayer(s, "dsm")
    dtmLayer  = QgsRasterLayer(t, "dtm")

    if not dsmLayer.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"
    if not dtmLayer.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"

    entries = []

    boh1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    boh1.ref = 'boh@1'
    boh1.raster = dsmLayer
    boh1.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( boh1 )

    boh2 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    boh2.ref = 'boh@2'
    boh2.raster = dtmLayer
    boh2.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( boh2 )

    # Process calculation with input extent and resolution
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator( 'boh@1 - boh@2', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/%s_dem_out.tif' % (i), 'GTiff', dsmLayer.extent(), dsmLayer.width(), dsmLayer.height(), entries )
    calc.processCalculation()

    print "Processed DEM %s" % (i+1)
```

Hope this helps anybody with similar issues!